# How to set up Cordova/PhoneGap for android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to setup Cordova/PhoneGap for hours now but I am in a huge mess.

**What I did:**

- Downloaded the PhoneGap zip package and used the create command to create a project but the jar wont build on using `ant jar` command but I got an error saying `BUILD FAILED
  Target "jar" does not exist in the project`.
- Tried to [install Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) via CLI after downloading successfully, and creating the project with `Cordova does not regognize the command create` I got the error while using `cordova create` command. (Yes, it said 'regognize'). I have also registered the Environment Variable for the "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\" directory.

**When I tried running the same command from the npm directory, it worked:**

```
C:\Users\Aniket\AppData\Roaming\npm>cordova create HelloWorld com.example.hello "Hello World"
Creating a new cordova project with name "Hello World" and id "com.example.hello
" at location "C:\Users\Aniket\AppData\Roaming\npm\HelloWorld"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Download complete
```

**At the next step, I encountered the same error:**

```
C:\Users\Aniket\AppData\Roaming\npm>cd HelloWorld

C:\Users\Aniket\AppData\Roaming\npm\HelloWorld>cordova platform add android
Cordova does not regognize the command platform
```

How do I fix this issue? What is the proper way of doing this? Please guide me.

Also, which installation should I go for? [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/install/) (phonegap-2.9.1.zip) or [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) by Apache?

Should I use `cordova-3.3.0-src.zip` or install from CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install nodejs: http://nodejs.org/,

To Install 3.3: Ensure that you have NodeJS installed, then open your commandline and run the following:

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Once installation completes, you can invoke phonegap on command line for further help.

Usage

phonegap create my-app
   cd my-app
   phonegap run android

Comment: Why not Cordova? Will try and report. Thanks.

Comment: this is the explanation: http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/ and you also need nodejs: http://cordova.apache.org/ . Best Regards!!

Comment: Why can't I run it from eclipse? It doesn't seem to interpret the imported project as an android project. Look at this: http://imgbin.org/images/16690.png

Comment: I do not use eclipse and windows, You can take a look here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html.

Comment: @AniDroid By the screenshot from your comments I saw the project was not imported as an Android project. You should be able to right click on the project, select import, then expand the 'Android' level and select 'Existing Android code into Workspace'.  You may need to create an Android project in Eclipse before doing this, not sure. If you don't see any Android stuff in your Eclipse then you need to download the ADT bundle or the Eclipse Android Developers Tool plugin.

Comment: I imported it as an Android project for sure and I use official ADT bundle from google

Answer (score 0):

Setup environment variables in your path.According to your downloaded drive.

```
E:\ant\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin;
E:\Node;
E:\Eclipse\sdk\platform-tools;
E:\Eclipse\sdk\tools;
C:\Users\Account\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

Comment: Already done that and verified. The issue seems to be something else.